# SharePoint 2013 Create Only Time Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to create a simple list column with the type of time and use it like a Start Time - End Time.

Recently, I found this [sptimeonly](https://sptimeonly.codeplex.com/) and that's exactly all I really need. Unfortunately, looking at the instructions, I don't think it will work on SharePoint 2013 as it was obviously made for SharePoint 2010.

What choices do I have? 
Do I need to develop some kind of custom field?
Is there any recommendation of where to start learning it? Kinda new to this platform, I'm sorry if these questions seem pretty basic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using DateTime column with a default value of the Date set,

Then adding content editor webpart in the EditForm.aspx to embed css in order to hide the Date part.